# Change Div height jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the style of my div from

```
<div id="map" style="height:25%;"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="map" style="height:0%;"></div>
```

On a click

jQuery

```
$('hideMap').css({"height":"0%"});
```

```
<li><a name="hideMap" class="btn red"><i class="material-icons" style="color:white;">notifications_active</i></a></li></li>
```

Thanks in advance if you can assist :)

Comment: $('#map').css({"height":"0%"});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('hideMap').css({"height":"0%"});`

do u want change the height of map div then you can write  below code

`$('#map').css({"height":"0%"});`

below is the working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7cfcfrnr/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#map').css("height","0");
```

Comment: This did hide my div, but not on activation of the <li> button.

Answer (score 0):

Your div id is `map` and you need to use `#` for id and `.` for class  name in jquery selector.

Change `$('hideMap').css({"height":"0%"});` to `$('#map').css({"height":"0%"});`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('map').style.height = '50%';
```

Jquery:

```
$("#map").height("50%");
```